# Differences between nested SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, where-clause

This is the original statement which I refer to

```
select * 
from CSDokument
where FirmaPubIndex in (select firmapubindex 
                        from CSDokument 
                        where dokumenttyp = '3' 
                          and ProjPubIndex in (select PubIndex 
                                               from CSProjekt 
                                               where Projektnummer = 209806)
                       )
  and ProjPubIndex in (select PubIndex 
                       from CSProjekt 
                       where Projektnummer = 209806)
  and DokumentTyp = '2'
```

I don't understand why these two statements from the first `where` return different results. I wonder why this statement returns 9926 results

```
select firmapubindex
from CSDokument
where FirmaPubIndex in (select firmapubindex 
                        from CSDokument 
                        where dokumenttyp = '3' 
                          and ProjPubIndex in (select PubIndex  
                                               from CSProjekt 
                                               where Projektnummer = 209806)
                       )
```

And this returns 144:

```
select firmapubindex 
from CSDokument 
where dokumenttyp = '3'
  and ProjPubIndex in (select PubIndex 
                       from CSProjekt 
                       where Projektnummer = 209806)
```

In both I select from `CSDokument` these rows which are `dokumenttyp`='3' and the `ProjPubIndex` is in table `CSProjekt` and has the `Projektnummer` = 209806.

Comment: Also tag your RDBMS (oracle, sql server, etc)

Comment: To make the query perform better change the use of `IN` to `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the  `where` clause first gets *firmapubindex* values that appear together with *dokumenttyp* equal to 3.

But then you select records that have such *firmapubindex* values. You *will* get those with *dokumenttyp* 3, but also others. That is why you get a lot more.

Imagine this data, assuming they are all linked to the correct *CSProjekt*:

```
firmapubindex | dokumenttyp
--------------+------------
    10        |    1
    10        |    2
    10        |    3
    20        |    1
    30        |    3
```

The following `select`:

```
select firmapubindex 
from   CSDokument 
where  dokumenttyp='3' and 
       ProjPubIndex in ( 
         select PubIndex from CSProjekt where Projektnummer = 209806 )
```

... will return:

```
firmapubindex 
-------------
    10        
    30
```

Now see what the outer `select` does when you wrap it around that:

```
select * 
from   CSDokument
where  FirmaPubIndex in 
       (select firmapubindex 
        from   CSDokument 
        where  dokumenttyp='3' and 
               ProjPubIndex in ( 
                  select PubIndex from CSProjekt where Projektnummer = 209806 )
       )
```

... it will list these records, because of the matching *firmapubindex*:

```
firmapubindex | dokumenttyp
--------------+------------
    10        |    1
    10        |    2
    10        |    3
    30        |    3
```

So that is why you need to filter on the *dokumenttyp* value (and *Projektnummer*) again.

#### Considerations

Now to the meaning of your query: if this is the complete picture, then there is no sense in first checking that the *firmapubindex* is in the result set that you are about to produce, since that is a tautology (i.e., is always true).

So the following two queries will return the same result set:

```
select * 
from   CSDokument
where  FirmaPubIndex in (
            select firmapubindex 
            from   CSDokument 
            where  dokumenttyp = '3' 
            and    ProjPubIndex in (select PubIndex 
                                    from   CSProjekt 
                                    where  Projektnummer = 209806)
        )
and    ProjPubIndex in (select PubIndex 
                        from   CSProjekt 
                        where  Projektnummer = 209806)
and    DokumentTyp = '3'
```

and:

```
select * 
from   CSDokument
where  FirmaPubIndex is not null 
and    ProjPubIndex in (select PubIndex 
                        from   CSProjekt 
                        where  Projektnummer = 209806)
and    DokumentTyp = '3'
```

The `is not null` test is still necessary, as the `in` operator will always yield `false` when the left side of it is `null`.

Comment: Detailed explanation and alternative with "is not null" was also very helpful. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Those are different queries. Consider

```
CSDokument
firmapubindex dokumenttyp Projektnummer 
1 3 209806 
1 0 0
```

The second query will return only one row, and it will have `firmapubindex=1`. So both rows will be returned by the first query.